# android application localization suggestions

Tags: android, localization

I am working on an android application which has to be translated into several languages. We plan to get the work done using external translation services. Is there a consolidated approach in dealing with such a situation? Platforms, services, softwares? For example, I don't think that just exposing the xml files to people not used to them will be a good idea. Any hint would be much appreciated!

Comment: thank you all for the answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a professional translation, Translated.net offers a dedicated service for Android apps localization: http://www.translated.net/en/android-apps-localization

They integrate the Google Translator Toolkit (GTT) in the translation process.

From this page you can also have access to other useful sources and tools to choose which countries and languages will your application support.

Answer (score 0):

I think GetLocalisation will probably do what you need:

http://www.getlocalization.com/

Answer (score 0):

In our case we used automated translation using the Google Translation API. I built a quick simple application in .NET and pay the very small amount Google charges for their API usage. 
The application parses the XML, translates into the desired application and produces the strings.xml file. This is then automatically saved into a new folder appropriately named for the language.

It only took me around an hour to make (its not polished :)) but works very well.

Some comments on the market state the translation isn't perfect but usable.

Just a thought.

[New version of Android LED Clock just uploaded to market](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.andronicus.ledclock)

Answer (score 0):

There are several web applications that allow you to allow translators to edit resource diles on the web, without XML or other technical knowledge. To name a few:

- [Amanuens](http://amanuens.com) (disclaimer: my company builds this product)
- [Transifex](http://www.transifex.net)
- [Get Localization](http://www.getlocalization.com)